# why doesn't this simple html code work? (pattern)

Tags: html, regex

could somebody tell me why this simple code doesn't work?
I type a random email address with .com at the end and I receive an error that this address doesn't have the right format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<form action="demo_form.asp">
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" pattern="\.com$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it works

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" pattern="+\.com$">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern. It will validate only .com emails.

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.com$"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your pattern, try using this instead
 `pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"`

Comment: There is no need for this as type=email will validate that it is an email address.  The op is trying to validate the email address so it ends with `.com`

Comment: Oh right, then you want the first answer with the "+\.com$"